# How to adjust histogram only in one channel in imagemagick?

Tags: imagemagick

I have an image that want to adjust to look like a target image.

With the following adjustment I get closer to the target image, but I see a big difference in the red channel, specially in the shadows, my question is how can I adjust only this channel to get the result?

My command:

```
convert actual_srgb.jpg -contrast-stretch 4x0.8% bb_4x0.8.jpg
```

(BTW, I've applied sRGB profile to the initial image with the Adobe RGB profile)

source:

[image]

[image]

[image]

My result: (See the Red channel)

[image]
[image]
[image]

Target:

[image]
[image]
[image]

Answer (score 0):

If you want to adjust just one channel in Imagemagick, then add -channel X to your command where X is R or G or B

```
convert actual_srgb.jpg -channel R -contrast-stretch 4x0.8% +channel bb_4x0.8.jpg
```

to adjust just the red channel for example.

Comment: Thanks for your help, I tried it but it doesn't make the change I need. I need to shift the histogram in the shadows more towards the darker areas without changing the bright side (if it makes sense).

Comment: If you want to make the darker values even darker while maintaining the high values nearly where they are, then just change the first value of -contrast stretch and leave the second value at 0. So try `convert actual_srgb.jpg -channel R -contrast-stretch 4x0% +channel bb_4x0.jpg`. That should work. I do not understands why it would not. There is not an easy way to only stretch in one part without affecting the others in some way with a linear stretch using only two values.